# Where are the Sanskrit texts of Upanishads referred by Dara Shikoh?

Tags: scripture, vedas, history, upanishads, sanskrit

[Wikipedia states](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dara_Shikoh) :

> Dara Shikoh subsequently developed a friendship with the seventh Sikh Guru, Guru Har Rai. Dara Shikoh devoted much effort towards finding a common mystical language between Islam and Hinduism. Towards this goal he completed the translation of fifty Upanishads from their original Sanskrit into Persian in 1657 so that they could be studied by Muslim scholars.

Where are the 50 Sanskrit Upanishads which were referred by Dara Shikoh?

Comment: Are you looking for original Sanskrit Upanishads or Sirr-e-akbar (Dara Shikoh's translated work)? Or do you just want a list of those 50 Upanishads which are translated by Dara Shikoh?

Comment: @Pandya The original Sanskrit Upanishads which were used by Dara Shikoh.

Comment: ok. Btw, I don't know which are those 50 but you get get a list of 108 Upanishads [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muktik%C4%81) and you can get the original Sanskrit  [Mukhya Upanishads](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_Upanishads) at [Sanskrit Documents](http://sanskritdocuments.org/sanskrit/by-category/doc_upanishhat.php).